# Rails - Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rubygems

I had used below mentioned commands to install rails in ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install curl

\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm requirements

rvm install 1.9.3

rvm use 1.9.3 --default

rvm rubygems current

gem install rails
```

Every steps are doing good, but it works for terminal which we are installing rails.  If we exit from the terminal and work on a new terminal then the following error occurs.

The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install

Help me to install rails.

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the rvm script into your shell.

Put this at the end of your .zshrc or .bashrc or whatever depending on your shell :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: I can't make use of this command, if u can plz instruct step by step process how to put this code at the end of .bashrc file.

Comment: open it with a text editor, for instance, gedit : ```gedit ~/.bashrc```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what exactly your problem is. If you use `rvm` and have installed Rails with it, you may have to use

`rvm use 1.9.3` after `gem install rails`.

Then you may or may have not a `gemset` with this. So:

```
bundle install
```

should install Rails gem in this `gemset`. Maybe use

`rvm sudo bundle install`

or just manually install the Rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm --default use 1.9.3-p374

By running the following code at each terminal Ruby on rails get starts to work.
This problem is occurred because

Comment: sorry for such a delay reply, plz tell me the reason why this happens

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal preferences and make sure the "run command as a login shell" option is checked in the "title and command" tab, it will load the ~/.bash_profile which contains something like "[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" and set the  rvm env for you.